# C fork function strange behaviour on Unix (HP-UX)

Tags: c, fork

I have the classic fork code on a C program as follows:

```
int status;


if((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
 printf("SOME fork() ERROR...\n");
}
else if(pid == 0)
{
 //Child stuff
 printf("CHILD CODE\n");
}
else
{
 //parent stuff
 printf("PARENT CODE\n");
 while (wait(&status) != pid);

}
```

It compiles OK, and I was running it to do some tests until something I don't understand happened:
Suddenly in the terminal I only saw written "PARENT CODE". As I understand if the child process is not created "SOME fork() ERROR..." and "PARENT CODE" is what must be displayed on screen. (Is this true?) But only the last appears. My first thought was mmmm... the fork succeeded but.. the child doesn't execute it's code?????????? Is this even possible?

Thanks for you time and help.

Edit: the variable status and wait(...) are on the program, I only print messages to try the see what is happening in a simpler manner.

It's HP-UX 11

Thanks to all for your answers.

Comment: Is this ALL the code you used to recreate the problem?  Can you paste all of it?  Is it always reproducible?  What version of HPUX?

Comment: Maybe try suspending/catching signals in the parent and child.  Maybe HPUX sends a signal to the child and kills it off for some reason?  Shot in the dark here...

Comment: SIGPIPE could kill it during the printf(), however, that makes very little sense here given the current context.

Comment: There should be no problem. How many did you run your example?

Comment: Actually Dimitri I was wondering if it's some sort of memory problem because I ran it many consecutive times. Maybe not enough time between them could cause this?

Comment: A complete, compilable-and-runnable example that demonstrates the problem would be far more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

How is `pid` declared?

Is it possible that it's an unsigned type (instead of using the type `pid_t` which should be signed)?  If that's the case, an error return from `fork()` won't be detected as such.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't let enough time for the child. Try to add a `waitpid()` call in the parent code.

Comment: I doesn't matter. If the wait is called before the child ends, the parent will halt until it happens, either way, the child will be a zombie and will be finished when parent does the wait.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`s.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange in the code: the child process doesn't exit.

```
else if(pid == 0)
{
    //Child stuff
    printf("CHILD CODE\n");
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Maybe this solves the problem.